# redirect rule for multiple pages

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, redirect

I have page not found erros in webmaster because the page/2/0 part of a url is due to smart paging module clean url feature (Drupal) now i uninstalled the smart paging module but these page not found errors are still there.

```
www.mysite.com/a/b/c/page/2/0, 
www.mysite.com/a/d/e/page/3/0, 
www.mysite.com/a/f/g/page/4/0, 
www.mysite.com/a/h/i/page/5/0
```

and so on.

I want to redirect

```
www.mysite.com/a/b/c/page/2/0 to  www.mysite.com/a/b/c
www.mysite.com/a/d/e/page/3/0, to www.mysite.com/a/d/e
www.mysite.com/a/f/g/page/4/0, to www.mysite.com/a/f/g
www.mysite.com/a/h/i/page/5/0  to www.mysite.com/a/h/i
```

with one redirect rule. How to do this

in short i want to remove the page/x/0 part from the url and redirect it to the remaining part of that url.

Comment: Please re-write your question in a more understandable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page/[0-9]+/0$ /$1/$2/$3 [L,R=301]
```

The literals here are after the first 3 path nodes: `/anything/anything/anything/`, then it *must* be followed by a `page`, then some numbers, then *a zero*. You can make it even more general, say after the "page", by changing the pattern to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page/ /$1/$2/$3 [L,R=301]
```